# WPF - bind cell style to nested object properties

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid

I have a `CellStyle` that I want to apply to several columns.  My view model contains several nested object, all of the same type.  I'd like to "bind" each of these objects to a column, where various elements of the cell are binded to different properties of the nested object.  See bad schematic below:

```
ViewModel Object (source object for a datagrid row)
    SubObj1   --> column 1                (set binding in column definition)
        PropA  -> column 1 text           (as defined in CellStyle)
        PropB  -> column 1 background     (as defined in CellStyle)
        PropC  -> column 1 whatever       (as defined in CellStyle)
    SubObj2   --> column 2                (set binding in column definition)  
        PropA  -> column 2 text           (as defined in CellStyle)
        PropB  -> column 2 background     (as defined in CellStyle)
        ....
```

So ideally, when I declare the columns I give them each this CellStyle and point the column binding to a particular nested object.  After that, the CellStyle should automatically handle all the bindings to the nested object's properties.

But I can't figure out how make the cell style to define binding that points to the properties inside of SubObjX?  If I set a property to `{Binding PropA}` then it just assumes I looking at the row view model, not the nested object.  I can't explicitly type the sub object name if I want the style to be reused for lots of columns.

I don't know if I'm on the right track with this approach, but since I'm binding to multiple cell components this seems the most logical structure.